# array must not contain infs or NaNs when changing np.linspace

Tags: python, numpy

I am performing sensitivity analysis in Python and want to produce scatterplots to show my system's results. I have been getting results with `np.linspace(0,100,100)`, but I want to increase my time to be `np.linspace(0,1000,100)` to see more results in the scatterplot. For some unknown reason, when I increase my time interval, my system does not evaluate (even though time should not make a difference). I also get a `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars return 1+((10*(A^n))/((A^n)+1))` along the way (this could possibly be a division by zero or an infinity) but I am not sure where it is crashing and what from. I've tried changing the parameter ranges to be very small for the sensitivity analysis but alas nothing removes this error.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy import integrate as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

def H(A):
    if A<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+((10*(A**n))/((A**n)+1))
    
def Hill(A):
    if A<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (A**n)/((A**n)+1)

def NDMsignals(time,Z,iota,upsilon,vartheta,varphi1,varphi2):
    dZdt = [(H(Z[0])*iota)-(upsilon*Z[0])+(Z[1]*varphi1), #A1
    (H(Z[1])*vartheta)-(upsilon*Z[1])+(Z[0]*varphi2)] #A2
    return dZdt

def main(iota,upsilon,vartheta,varphi1,varphi2):
    alpha1 = 0.1
    alpha2 = 0.1
    gamma = 0.75
    n=2.2
    d1 = 1.0
    d2 = 1.0
    beta1 = 10*alpha1
    beta2 = 10*alpha2
    mu1 = 6.0
    mu2 = 6.0
    Upsilon1 = 1.0
    Upsilon2 = 1.0
    c1not = 1.0
    c2not = 1.0
    b1 = 1.0
    b2 = 1.0
    k1 = 0.4
    k2 = 0.4
    sigma1 = 1.0
    sigma2 = 1.0
    tau1 = 0.75
    tau2 = 0.75

    time=np.linspace(0,1000,100)

    Zinitial = [0.1, 0.1]

# Dimensional Parameters

    u = (gamma+b1+b2)
    psi = (tau1/tau2)
    c1eq = (sigma1*k1)/(mu1-k1)
    c2eq = (sigma2*k2)/(mu2-k2)
    xeq = (Upsilon1/k1)*((d1*(c1not-c1eq))-(d2*c1eq)+(d2*c2eq))
    yeq = (Upsilon2/k2)*((d1*(c2not-c2eq))-(d2*c2eq)+(d2*c1eq))

    # NDM Parameters
   
    #iota = (xeq)/(tau1)
    #upsilon = (u/alpha1)
    #vartheta = (alpha2*yeq)/(alpha1*tau2)
    #varphi1 = (b1/(psi*alpha1))
    #varphi2 = ((b1*psi)/alpha1)
    
    sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, Z: NDMsignals(time,Z,iota,upsilon,vartheta,varphi1,varphi2), 
                    [time[0],time[-1]], Zinitial, method='BDF', t_eval=time)
    #print([sol.y[0][-1], sol.y[1][-1]])
    return [sol.y[0][-1], sol.y[1][-1], Hill(sol.y[0][-1]), Hill(sol.y[1][-1])]

# Sensitivity Analysis

from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol

problem = {
    'num_vars': 5,
    'names':['iota', 'upsilon', 'vartheta', 'varphi1', 'varphi2'],
    'bounds': [[0.01, 10],
              [0.01, 35],
              [0.01, 10],
              [0.01, 3],
              [0.01, 3]]
}

param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 200)

Y1 = np.zeros([param_values.shape[0]])
Y2 = np.zeros([param_values.shape[0]])
Y3 = np.zeros([param_values.shape[0]])
Y4 = np.zeros([param_values.shape[0]])

for i, X in enumerate(param_values):
    xx = main(X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4])
    Y1[i] = xx[0]
    Y2[i] = xx[1]
    Y3[i] = xx[2]
    Y4[i] = xx[3]

#Si1 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y1, print_to_console=True)
#Si2 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y2, print_to_console=True)
#Si3 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y3, print_to_console=True)
#Si4 = sobol.analyze(problem, Y4, print_to_console=True)

plt.scatter(Y3,Y4)
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: time=np.linspace(0,1000,100) creates 100 values starting with the value 0 until the value 1000.   division by zero should be traceable in a try catch block with exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
time[0] #produces the first value=0
time[-1] #produces the last value=1000

NDMsignals does not use the time list [0,100]

The way your passing variables is hazardous.   Instead, create a class with self variables in the __init__ then use the constructor to initialize the variables.  After which make method calls for your calculation separating primary methods as publicly exposing and private as the internal methods.
```